# PayPal - Redirect to checkout page from server side instead of smart button

Tags: paypal

I'm relatively new to payment integrations.

I'm just wondering if, it is possible for me to redirect customers to PayPal's checkout page by returning a url for the checkout page from the backend, instead of using PayPal's Smart button?

Tbh, I am having a hard time looking at their documentations. So please bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible, but it is an old integration pattern. For current web checkouts, pairing the smart button with a server-side integration is a superior UX in every respect. Here's the code to use for the approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

This way you never have to redirect away to another (possibly unfamiliar) site and back; your site stays loaded contextually in the background at every moment. Also it has an incline "Debit or Credit Card" button you can include as desired.